# How to Get ByteArray of Classes in ASM

Tags: java, arrays, method-call

I am trying to implement method call application with CHA,XTA,RTA .For this purpose i use ASM.What should be bytecode variable below?How can i traverse all classes of Java project.

```
ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(bytecode);
ClassNode cn = new ClassNode();
cr.accept(cn, ClassReader.SKIP_DEBUG);

  List methods = cn.methods;
  for (int i = 0; i < methods.size(); ++i) {
       MethodNode method = (MethodNode) methods.get(i);
       if (method.instructions.size() > 0) {..}
  }
```

Comment: Q: What exactly are you trying to do?  Interface Java and assembler (is that what you mean by "asm")?  If so, you need to look at JNI: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/

Comment: Asm Java bytecode manipulation and analysis framework.http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/index.html.I am trying to implement method call graph of a Java project using some method call graph construction algoritjm like XTA,CHA..

Answer (score 1):

Each class is in its own file.  You traverse classes, in the same manner as you traverse files. e.g.

```
 public static void traverse(File dir) {
     for(File file: dir.listFiles()) {
         if (file.isDirectory())
             traverse(file);
         else
             processWithASM(file);
     }
 }
```

If the classes are in a JAR or ZIP file, you need to read that file.